# mongoid where and association value is nil

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm a little lost with mongoid queries. I have a user that has one company.
Here is the model

```
class Company
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :name,                        :type => String
    field :description,         :type => String
    field :order_minimun,       :type => Float

    belongs_to :user

  def candidate_users
    User.where(:company_id => nil)
  end

end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    ROLES = %w[admin company_owner customer]

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
  field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :default => ""

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :encrypted_password

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   :type => String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, :type => Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, :type => Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      :type => Integer, :default => 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, :type => Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    :type => Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, :type => String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    :type => String

    field :name,               :type => String
    field :last_name,          :type => String
    validates_presence_of :name
    #validates_uniqueness_of :name, :email, :case_sensitive => false

    field :roles_list,                  :type => Array , :default => ['customer']
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false

    has_one :company
end
```

I want to list of the users that not has a company, and the user that owns the company instance.

My first attempt (just of the users which don't have a company):

```
  def candidate_users
    User.where(:company_id => nil)
  end
```

the somethig like this

```
def candidate_users
    User.any_of(:company_id => self.id, :company_id => nil)
  end
```

But I have no luck, that returns all the users.

Someone can helpme with this query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having trouble with your first query or your second?

Comment: Thanks. both queries return all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mongoid, the `foreign field` is always on the side of the `belongs_to` association. So `Company` objects will have a `user_id` field, but `User` objects won't have a `company_id` field. So it is "normal" for your queries to return all users

Since there is no notion of join in mongodb, you can achieve this either by reversing the association (user belongs_to company, company has_one user), or you can do two queries :

```
# First, finding ids of users that have a company
ids = Company.excludes(user_id: nil).only(:_id).map(&:id)

# Then, find users whose ids are not in that array
users = User.not_in(_id: ids)
```

Still keeping the part about `any_of`:

`any_of` is doing a `$or` query for all hashes arguments. By doing `User.any_of(:company_id => self.id, :company_id => nil)`, you're supplying only array, which is the same as `User.where(:company_id => self.id, :company_id => nil)`. What I think you want to do is `User.any_of({:company_id => self.id}, {:company_id => nil})`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That does not work. But i think this i because in the document there is no company_id, the company object has the user_id. I think i can no join user with company in the query, Am I Wrong? Sorrey, i'm new in nosql databases

Comment: I edited my answer. Didn't paid enough attention to your question yesterday.